# Free SWF Obfuscator

Tags: encryption, flash, obfuscation, source-code-protection

Does anybody know of a free flash obfuscator(protector)? All I can find are commercial ones with free trials. I have done numerous google searches, and have been unable to find what I am looking for.

I know that obfuscators do not make your swf hack proof, but they make things harder.

Things I am looking for in an obfuscator:

- Unlimited obfuscations
- No time limit
- No watermark (or on the left side only! Right side is no good, same with center)
- Able to publish work (no special player needed other than standard flashplayer)

I really was surprised to see how hard it was to find a good obfuscator (tried encoder, protection, etc. instead as well) and how easy it is to find a decompiler....

It is imperative that my code be protected, at least partially, to discourage the hacking of my game.

Comment: **HEREE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!------->>>** [**Free SWF protect PROGRAMS**](http://bruce-lab.blogspot.com/2012/04/free-swf-encryptor-obfuscator-and.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

amayeta swfencrypt - http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/  <= this one existed for a long time and is up to date

secureSWF http://www.kindisoft.com/secureSWF/download.php <== this one fulfill no time limit, but has watermark

and since actionscript format is very like javascript, you can use online free javascript obfuscator like this one to obfuscate sections of the important code
http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx

or you can search for more at here http://www.google.com/search?q=obfuscator+javascript

Comment: See above for response to swfencrypt. Secureswf does not allow project publish features, I cannot use it.

As for the JS obfuscator, I might as well just make my variables really long and random, like das2ghrg23yrghfy4fgt4y0gfuy9 instead of a word or phrase. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Free SWFEncript is currently available at http://www.amayeta.com/promo/mag/

Comment: The free SWFEncrypt offers no protection. Trillix decompiled it for me just fine.

Comment: @Cyclone Do you mean that Secureswf requires a special Flash Player type to run the swfs?

Answer (score 4):

I've found:

- http://makc3d.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/open-source-swf-obfuscator/
- http://github.com/shapedbyregret/actionscript-3-obfuscator
- [SOB](http://git.runtimeterror.com/?p=sob.git;a=summary)

All open source, all free. I haven't tried any of them yet.

Answer (score 2):

A coworker did some research on the topic a few months ago, and didn't find any free SWF obfuscators. We ended up picking SWF Encrypt (http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/) which seems to do a good job.

Comment: Only allows for 25, but I guess its okay. How big is the watermark?

Comment: I think you need to see this http://www.swfdecrypt.com/

Comment: @Ammar You got two upvotes, so I figure your comment is probably a good one; but when I go to that site, I see almost nothing.  What's lost in translation?

Comment: That comment is 3 years old, that site is no longer online.

Answer (score 2):

[OBFU](http://tech.motion-twin.com/obfu.html) - 1500 euros!

[Amayeta SWF Encrypt Pro 5.0](http://www.amayeta.com/shop/) - $125 USD. [gets "bypassed" too](http://www.asvguy.com/2007/02/swf_encrypt_swc.html)

[SecureSWF](http://www.kindisoft.com/secureSWF/) - Looks like the most promising right now.

[A list of decompilers and obfuscators](http://www.bestflashanimationsite.com/resources/decompilers/)

Found at http://www.balsamiq.com/blog/2008/10/19/my-views-on-software-piracy/

Comment: SecureSWF leaves a watermark unfortunately....

Comment: SecureSWF also broke my application when I turned on the "encrypt names" feature. Without it the entire source code hierarchy is clearly visible (class names, package names)..

Answer (score 1):

I found SWFProtect. It looks decent, but You'll have to test it to be sure.
http://www.swfprotect.net/swf2.0/index.php

Update: Amayeta SWF Encrypt Version 4 is now being offered for free.
http://www.amayeta.com/promo/mag/

Comment: Bit expensive, thanks anyway.