# Restricting SWF file visibility

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security

I have a situation where my main SWF file loads many external SWF files. However, those external SWF files are just sitting in the public folder of the web server.

Is it possible to restrict the SWF visibility to only my main SWF file (the one that loads the external SWFs). In the current state, any user who knows where to look can just type in the URL and get to the SWFs, not to mention rogue bots that don't follow robots.txt.

The reason for this is very simple. Users user a username/password to log into the main Flash application and the main Flash application in turn loads the SWF files and ONLY then they are available to the user. Also, depending on who the logged in user is, some SWF files are restricted and not loaded.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Flash so I don't know what Flash specific possibilities exist for this, but this could be solved by doing the login in a server-side language like PHP or ASP. A login would create a session, and a valid session would be the condition for the delivery of the subsequent files.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. I was entertaining this idea, but I'm pretty sure Flash can only load external assets (including SWFs) by requesting a URL (SWFs cannot be delivered *to* it). If true, Flash will never be able to reach SWFs if they are protected in any way.

Comment: Just had another thought. Isn't it possible to prevent a directory from listing by modifying .htacess? So it can't list, but you can still open files if you know the exact name. Perhaps it's possible to make the name impossible* to get by appending a hash to the end of the filename.

*practically impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how flash is authenticating.   Flash needs to authenticate with a server side application with a database.  The server side application can then use a database to perform access control on a per-file basis.

All `files` should be tracked by a table,  contains columns such as the local `path` to the file as well as `user_group` or perhaps a `user_id`.  The authenticated session should keep track of the `user_id` after they have logged in with a username and password.

It is common for attack spiders to use robots.txt against you,  if you put these file paths in your robots.txt you are better off just zip them up and give them to the attacker.

It is very easy to decompile flash applications and modify them.   Do not rely on "client side"  security systems,  they are very easy to bypass. An attacker can also replay and modify HTTP requests using tamperdata.  You need a server to tell the client what files it can access.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I was thinking about using a method like this, but the problem is if the external SWFs are in a protected directory i.e. not publicly visible, then Flash wouldn't be able to load them either, right?

I think main problem is that you can't pass SWF objects into a Flash application. Only a Flash application can load SWF objects by referring to an actual URL. 

So maybe it's not possible? :-(

Comment: Well I suppose if it's not possible I'll have to come to some sort of compromise. The copyright issue regarding SWFs is slightly complex but that's the nature of the business requirement.

If it's a security compromise then I have to make that clear to my client. A usability compromise could be another way to go. Perhaps I can turn it into a AIR desktop application instead and users will log into the web application and see the SWFs "belonging" to them available for download. They they download those SWF files from the server onto their computer so that the AIR app can access those files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how secure you want to be, I can think of a couple of options:

1. A server-side script to control delivery of your sub-swfs (as Pekka has suggested above).
2. If want to do everything client-side, you could put a conditional test within each sub-swf, so they will only play from inside your main swf:

Something like `if(this.parent.toString() != "mainSwf") { stop();}` (in pseudocode).

Granted, this isn't foolproof, since someone could easily make their own parent named "mainSwf", but it would deter casual browsing of your sub-swfs. At least until someone decompiles them...

You could make things slightly harder by setting a property within the main swf, such as `var myKey:String="362574036704ry3f0y3432607"`, then use your conditional to test for it: `if(this.parent.myKey != "362574036704ry3f0y3432607") { stop();}`.

Sill not terribly secure, though. Hope this helps.

---

EDIT:

There's also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326538/how-to-protect-swf-files-from-being-view), which might have useful answers.

Comment: -1 You can't propose a vulnerability on SO,  especially if you know its a vulnerability.   Decompiling flash or replaying GET requests with tamperdata can bypass your client side security system.

Comment: @The Rook: Hehe, I'll be sure to read the FAQ more carefully next time! But do let me know how you think GET sniffing is going to crack this method. And yes, sometimes a server-side solution isn't possible for other reasons... guess we live in an imperfect world. :)