# Secure swf using flash obfuscator?

Tags: flash, obfuscation

In order to protect swf files, prevent decompile and reading the action script CODE, now I am looking for best/popular(being used by big companies) flash obfuscator. Could you recommend some of the best flash obfuscators that you know?

(I am not sure if its an appropriate question to ask here. But its very important for action script programmers, hope you guys can help)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924081/free-swf-obfuscator

Answer (score 2):

I don't think obfuscating will prevent the code from being decompiled. It just makes it harder to decompile.

These are the flas obfuscators that I found

[irrFuscator ActionScript 3 Obfuscator](http://www.ambiera.com/irrfuscator/)

[secureSWF](http://www.kindisoft.com/)

[SWF Encrypt 6.0](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/)

Comment: I see.. Well at least, after decompile they cant read the AS code. Thats the most important thing

Comment: @bbtang It can be read in most of the cases. Sothink swf decompiler is good enough for this. You definitely can get the actionscript byte code assembly. And any intelligent one can figure things out.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are run on Virtual Machines with bytecodes, they can be easily decompiled. Obfuscation doesn't prevent this from happening. Obfuscation might help in case you just wanted to hide the exact implementation details. But anything like protection using serial numbers etc would be of no help. 
For obfuscators see the post by rahul.