# encrypting flash files

Tags: flash, encryption

what's the recommended method to encrypt flash files ?

i'd like to make some flash programs that are commericals, how can i made sure that they won't get decrypted or to make sure that i used to strongest file encryption possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to deliver the content using Flash Media Server. Using either TMPe, RTMPte or RTMPs protocols automatically encrypts delivered content.

http://blogs.adobe.com/ktowes/2008/09/encryption_and_streaming_media.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a code obfuscator, a nifty tool that makes your swf difficult to reverse engineer. When someone tries to decompile your swf, the source code will look like gibberish.

**Wikipedia Definition**

> Obfuscated code is source or machine
>   code that has been made difficult to
>   understand. Programmers may
>   deliberately obfuscate code to conceal
>   its purpose (a form of security
>   through obscurity), to deter reverse
>   engineering, or as a puzzle or
>   recreational challenge for readers.
>   Programs known as obfuscators
>   transform human-readable code into
>   obfuscated code using various
>   techniques.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

## Obfuscator Tools

**secureSWF**
well known, but it isn't free
http://www.kindisoft.com

**"Free SWF Obfuscator" Question on SA**
Great answers here...
[Free SWF Obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924081/swf-obfuscator)