# Actionscript - Obfuscation tool or plugin or script?

Tags: actionscript-3, obfuscation

Does anyone know of any good obfuscation tools, plugins and or scripts that will work well with Actionscript? Since AS3 is based on ECMAScript I'm guessing that Javascript obfuscators might work as well.
Ideally I'm looking for something that would allow to set the level of obfuscation, or to only obfuscate parts of code, ie variables or private methods, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to protect your final SWFs, you'll need to obfuscate the SWF rather than obfuscating the source code.  While changing variable / function / etc names in the source code before compilation will provide some protection, it makes the process much more complex and misses out on several additional levels of possible obfuscation available by processing the compiled SWF.

There are numerous SWF obfuscators available; [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924081/free-swf-obfuscator) a topic that covers that (note all of the linked topics on the right-hand side).  My personal favorite is [secureSWF](http://www.kindi.com/).

Comment: I think the general rule of thumb here is that crackers are inherently lazy, otherwise they'd be writing their own code. Source-code obfuscation is a good first step, but I concur that the more layers of protection, the better. Just be aware - for every program that "secures" the SWF, there is someone working on cracking that form of security. Don't rely on any one technology to protect you. Source code obfuscation is a smart additional step to take, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Flash Secure Optimizer](http://eramsoft.com) cheap and secure

Answer (score -3):

There is no need to obfuscate your code since it is compiled and that will take care of it. Now if you are referring to a de-compiler then don't because it will correct all your obfuscation.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Many symbol names are stored in the bytecode, which would help someone de-compiling your code to understand how it works. An obfuscator could make that into nonsense.

Comment: And again pointless. Obfuscation is not the way to make a secure app

Comment: Not by much, no. But it it will certainly make it harder to use a decompiled swf file.