# how can i make this "swf" file hide or can't copied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, flash

I am developing a C# windows application in Microsoft visual Studio.
SWF flash uploaded as a local file will appears on a C# form.
Now, I want to publish the project.
Can you tell me how I can make this swf file hidden or copy protected?

Thanks in advance 
Regards.

Comment: Please rephrase the question with more details, its not clear at all.

Comment: Agreed with @AlexK. I'm guessing here. You want to copy protect a file you're distributing with your application? Consider "branding" it like networks do, with a logo, your company name or website address at the bottom of the video.

Comment: I mean that i have a intro. swf in my C# form and I want to publish this app.

Comment: i don't want to allow people copy this swf to them PC when they get application.

Comment: Asking the same question again just because the original is closed is NOT a good idea. **Improve the original then ask to reopen it.**

Answer (score 1):

Use obfuscator for your SWF file. You can find some in that question: [link][Free SWF Obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924081/free-swf-obfuscator)

In any other variation your file need to be downloaded into local system or application will not see it. Same goes for any image you want to use in app, even if you load anything from the web it will be downloaded to local TEMP directory first. You can  designate your own temp directory and hide it within application folder structure but that is all you can do.